# How to trace what is causing WordPress error 500?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, error-handling

Internal error 500 is such a general error and nothing shows up in the logs under /wordpress/error_log. Is there a way to get a stack trace of where the crash is occurring? In ASP.NET it is so easy because a stack trace, code snippet, and line number all show up in the error page. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A fuller explanation of the error *will* show up in the location where Apache writes the error logs. If it's not in /wordpress/error.log, then that is not the location where that takes place

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Turn on php errors in your php.ini or add this line to your .htacess file in your webroot:

```
php_flag display_errors on
```

Comment: Done both of these things and I still have no errors, just a default "Internal Server Error" page served up by my web browser.

Comment: @Bill (or anyone else coming along) - WordPress does funny stuff with error reporting based on constants. Look into the `WP_DEBUG`, `WP_DEBUG_LOG`, and `WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY` constants. For example in 4.7.3, WordPress will explicitly turn *off* `display_errors`, overriding your environment settings, if you have `WP_DEBUG` on but not `WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY`.

Comment: By contrast, `WP_DEBUG_LOG = true` will cause WordPress to clobber your `error_log` setting, pointing it to wp-content/debug.log instead, whereas `WP_DEBUG_LOG = false` (or omitted) will leave your `error_log` and `log_errors` alone.