# Upload Wordpress page to Cybderduck

Tags: wordpress, cyberduck

I have made a Wordpress website which I am going to upload to a server via Cyberduck.

When I upload the files I get a black page and nothing else. I do not really understand the whole structure of the files in Wordpress, so there might be something wrong with that.

I am very new at programming and making Wordpress sites from scratch (this is my first one), so I am sorry if I don't really make the problem clear.

I have attached a picture of the current file structure. [ [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClRqU.png][1]

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Which file(s) did you upload into the `/wp-content/themes/elnino`? One or all of them?

Comment: I uploaded my index.php, single.php, template.php boostrap files, css, images.. Basically everything. I also uploaded some plugins, that I have used on my site. Everything is working on Wordpress, but once I upload it via the server, it shows a blank page or it gives me this 500 internal server error :/

Comment: Try seeing what your php logs - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7576759/how-to-trace-what-is-causing-wordpress-error-500