# WordPress Custom Plugin Crashes on Trivial Code

Tags: php, wordpress

I've written a WP plugin to implement a custom REST API. It worked for a week or so and then it started crashing, so I've tried building it back one line at a time.

Currently, this code runs:

```php
<?php
/**
* Plugin Name: Telebar API
* Plugin URI: http://github.com/tuzmusic/QMGTelebarAPI/
* Description: API for Telebar
* Version: 1
* Author: Jonathan Tuzman
* Author URI: http://www.github.com/tuzmusic
*/
$dir = dirname(__FILE__);

register_rest_route($namespace, '/test', array(
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'test',
  ) 
);

function test() {
  return "hello";
}
```

Going to my Local site at https://telebar.local/wp-json/test gives a 404, because `$namespace` is undefined. Surprisingly, `$namespace` being undefined doesn't cause a crash.

However, if I define it, like this:

```php
$namespace = 'api/v1';

register_rest_route($namespace, '/test', array(
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'test',
  ) 
);

function test() {
  return "hello";
}
```

or even if I provide the string directly for the route:

```php
register_rest_route('api/v1', '/test', array(
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'test',
  ) 
);

function test() {
  return "hello";
}
```

The site crashes completely. The code I've included here is the *complete* contents of the plugin.

What is going wrong here?

Also, I'm pretty new to WordPress: Is there a place where I can see more (any??) information about the crash? Currently all I have is this from Chrome:

```
This page isn’t working telebar.local is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7576759/how-to-trace-what-is-causing-wordpress-error-500

Comment: I'm pretty sure WordPress is already using the "api" namespace and, well, maybe that's what the problem is. Call yours `telebar\v1` or something similar and try again.

Comment: Can you post the server error logs?

Comment: @atymic How do I find the error server logs? And, @cabrerahector I've used this same pattern (where my plugin uses `api/v1` namespace) in other sites with no problem. Also I don't think it would even be a problem, since I'd just be defining my own routes in that namespace?