# Order by date with ASC giving me 500 error in ajax call

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I am using WordPress, and I have to show the post from the old to the new order by date. I tried the below code but I am getting a 500 error in ajax calling.

Order by title is working but the order by date giving me an error.

```
$sort =array(  
         'post_type' => 'post',
         'post_status' => 'publish', 
         'order' =>'ASC',
         'orderby' => 'date' // This is not working
         //'orderby' => 'post_date' // This is not working
        //'orderby' => 'title', // This is working
    );
```

Full code here

```
function blogviewlist( $atts ){
global $post;
//echo $_REQUEST['keyword'];

$sort = array(  
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
    ); 


    if(!empty($_REQUEST['keyword'])){
       

    if ($_REQUEST['keyword']=="newtoold") {

            $sort =array(  
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'post_status' => 'publish', 
                'orderby' => 'date',
                'order' =>'DESC'
            );

        }
        elseif ($_REQUEST['keyword']=="oldtonew") {
            //echo $_REQUEST['keyword'];

            $sort =array(  
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'post_status' => 'publish', 
                'order' =>'ASC',
                'orderby' => 'date'
                
            );
            //print_r($sort);

        }
}
$getPost= new WP_Query( $sort );
if($getPost->have_posts()){

 $data='';
 $data.='<div class="blog-wrap">
          <div class="row">';
        while ( $getPost->have_posts()):$getPost->the_post();
        $is_featureimage = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );

$data.='<div class="col-lg-6 blog-post">
        <div class="blog-list-item">
            <a href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'"><div class="item-img" style="background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)),url('.$is_featureimage.')">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>';

 endwhile; 
     $data.='</div></div>';

    }
//}

 echo $data;
// die();   
 wp_die(); // it will remove 0.

}
```

I have added the below code in the function.php file at the top

ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

then I got the below error

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /srv/www/wordpress/wp-includes/meta.php on line 1175
```

I have added the below code in the htaccess file and it's started working.

```
php_value memory_limit 516M
```

Now my doubt is why it was not working with an order by **date** and working with an order by **title**

Comment: "I am getting a 500 error in ajax calling" - then you need to check for the error message. The code you've shared does not throw any error, it just defines a unused array

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error is a generic error message informing you that the server crashed while processing the request. Beyond that, it's (intentionally) meaningless, and is of very little use for debugging. You need to check the error logs on the server to try and find the underlying exception message. Once you've got that, you stand a chance of identifying the problem.

Comment: @NicoHaase, but same code working with title

Comment: @ADyson, the code which I shared is correct?

Comment: The code you've shared "works" in all cases, and it does not throw any error. I would assume that this is not the code that throws the error

Comment: let me update the whole code.. give me 5 mins

Comment: You need to check your error log to find the actual source of the error. It should tell you a message and a file name and line number. You may get a full stack trace as well. The code you've shown has no obvious issues by itself- if you still want help after viewing and investigating the error, please provide a [mre] of the issue in your question.

Comment: Note, not the "whole code", we only need enough to be able to reproduce the specific error. So you can't update your post until you know what the error is. And even then, you may find you're able to research and fix it yourself using existing info online. If not, then after attempting something, you should come back to us.

Comment: @ADyson, I am calling ajax on the change event, and in the network tab i am getting 500 errors,  in the response, I am getting There has been a critical error on this website.

Comment: but if I use the title instated of the date then everything works perfectly.

Comment: @ADyson, i have updated the code in the question. Can you please check it once?

Comment: Ok. So...again, for the 4th time...have you looked in the PHP error log to find what's causing the 500? That's the way forward here. Just staring at your code almost certainly isn't going to tell us what exception it's throwing

Comment: @ADyson, Yes, I have checked that, even I have set the ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 ); in load.php file to display the error but is also not showing any error.. it only displaying 'There has been a critical error on this website '

Comment: Maybe the error is written to your server's error log? If not, check your setting such that this happens. Then post the **real** error message

Comment: You looked in `/wordpress/error.log`, you mean? Also, wordpress may muck about with the error reporting settings, I believe. have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7576759/how-to-trace-what-is-causing-wordpress-error-500

Comment: @ADyson, There is no error.log file in the WordPress, Let me check your reference link

Comment: @ADyson, After some research, i have found the issue Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /srv/www/wordpress/wp-includes/meta.php on line 1175

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include this important info, then. It'll also bump your question back up the lists so more people might see it. If there's a full stack tace to see what was calling the meta.php file at the time, that would also be useful information, probably.

Comment: I have updated the code and information in the question